# Where would I post a question about a specific manufactured material and its properties?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I would like some information around a manufactured mesh material that is flexible and has other properties. Where would I post my questions?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not 100% sure (it's hard to be without seeing the exact question you want to ask), but I think your best bet is [Engineering Stack Exchange](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/). They have a tag [[materials]](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/tags/materials) which can be used for questions about manufacturing:

> Use for questions about designing, manufacturing or synthesizing engineered materials or about the properties of specific materials. Questions concerning common construction materials, such as wood, steel or masonry do not need to use this tag; use the more specific tag instead.

Please read their [Help Center article "What topics can I ask about here?"](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before asking, it has some advice for well-received questions on that site.